# Fail to use Array.find for the useSWR return in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am doing:

```js
const fetcher = (url: string) => axios.get(url).then((r) => r.data);

const {data} = useSWR("api/data", fetcher, {refreshInterval: 10000})
console.log(data.find(d => d.id === "123"))
```

The api route:

```
const promises = matchString.split(",").map(async (match: string) => {
    try {
      events.push(await Events.find({ name: match }).then((res) => res[0]))
    } catch (error) {
      events.push(error)
      console.log("model/route.js error")
    }
  })
  await Promise.all(promises)
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(events), { status: 200 });
```

However, the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
```

May I ask how I can solve it?

Comment: You need to account for the loading state

Comment: How should I do it? @yaakov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check data before executing `find()` method on it.

```
const {data, error} = useSWR("api/data", fetcher, {refreshInterval: 10000});

// check for error
if(error) return <h1>`Something went wrong: ${error}`</h1>

// if data is not available, return
if(!data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

console.log(data.find(d => d.id === "123"));
```

Comment: Share the code of the component where you got this error

Comment: it logged `undefined` the first time, after that no console.log appears.

Comment: Check you api and the fetcher function if you have written a custom fether.

Comment: I have added to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `filter()` method on array

Try this....

```
const {data} = useSWR("api/data", fetcher, {refreshInterval: 10000})
console.log(data?.filter(d => d.id === "123"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the loading state. The `useSWR` hook returns an `isLoading` property so you can display a loading state while the data loads.

https://swr.vercel.app/

```
import useSWR from 'swr'
 
function Profile() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('/api/user', fetcher)
 
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>
  return <div>hello {data.name}!</div>
}
```